# Python: compare list unable to print

Tags: python

Does not print && does not give error, why?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
prices = {"banana" : 4, "apple" : 2, "orange" : 1.5, "pear" : 3}
stock = {"banana" : 6, "apple" : 0, "orange" : 32, "pear" : 15}

for item in set(prices) & set(stock):
    if prices[item] == stock[item]:
        print item
        print "price: " + str(prices[item])
        print "stock: " + str(stock[item])
```

Comment: Why using (&)? Just asking.

Comment: There's no item for which `prices[item] == stock[item]`.

Comment: @Christian `&` does set intersection

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the values for each shared key, but none of these values are ever equal:

```
>>> for item in set(prices) & set(stock):
...     print '{:6}: {:3} == {:2} = {}'.format(item, prices[item], stock[item], prices[item] == stock[item])
... 
orange: 1.5 == 32 = False
pear  : 3   == 15 = False
banana: 4   == 6  = False
apple : 2   == 0  = False
```

The condition `prices[item] == stock[item]` is never True.

Answer (score 1):

Since in this:

```
set(prices) & set(stock)
```

you are doing the intersection, you will get all the common items between `prices` and `stock` (no need to check again), so you may want just print it:

```
for item in set(prices) & set(stock):
        print item
        print "price: " + str(prices[item])
        print "stock: " + str(stock[item])
```

**Output:**

```
orange
price: 1.5
stock: 32

pear
price: 3
stock: 15

banana
price: 4
stock: 6

apple
price: 2
stock: 0
```

**PS:** I'm assuming this is what OP expected.